# Receive MSB1006 whenever running dotnet ef migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Issue: 
Whenever I attempt to execute migrations in my solution I receive a cryptic error.

MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.

Example command executed:

```
dotnet ef migrations add
```

or

```
dotnet ef migrations script
```

Example Error Returned

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: \tmpBCE7.tmp

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core 
project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or 
MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath 
option.
```

On a whim I checked my environment variables and noticed that my TMP variable within User Variables had an added semicolon (As noted in the image). 
By deleting and re-adding the TMP environment variable without the added semicolon I was able to avoid the error when running migrations in my project. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Again, in my case, the issue was resolved by ensuring the TMP variable did not have any special characters appended. Removing the semicolon allowed my migration commands to run without errors.